# Convert INTEGER AND STRING datatype values with "REPEATED" mode in BigQuery table into a comma separated list

Tags: arrays, csv, google-bigquery

Most examples i have seen are of RECORD type but i have a table with normal INTEGER and STRING values which just have the MODE as REPEATED.
The below shows the current table in BigQuery , the EXPECTED output table i want to create in BigQuery.
ANd below that it shows the datatypes it shows in BigQuery.
Not able to use UNNEST in a way to get the required output.
How do i store The comma separated values as a STRING OR as an ARRAY ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Convert INTEGER AND STRING datatype values with "REPEATED" mode in BigQuery table into a comma separated list

For an array of string, [`ARRAY_TO_STRING()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_to_string) function would be enough. But it doesn't work for *array of integer*.

Alternatives for an integer array can be `FORMAT()` or `TO_JSON_STRING`.

If applying above functions to your table,

```
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '1234' pk, [5555, 5600] NumericField1, [6555, 6601] NumericField2, [] NumericField3, CAST(['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5'] AS ARRAY<STRING>) String_field
)
SELECT pk,
       NULLIF(TRIM(FORMAT('%t', NumericField1), '[]'), '') NumericField1,
       NULLIF(TRIM(FORMAT('%t', NumericField2), '[]'), '') NumericField2,
       NULLIF(TRIM(FORMAT('%t', NumericField3), '[]'), '') NumericField3,
       NULLIF(ARRAY_TO_STRING(String_field, ', '), '') String_field
  FROM sample_table;
```

- **FORMAT('%t', *repeated_column*)** returns a string in the shape of `[a, b, c]` with brackets.
- **TRIM(string, '[]')** removes brackets preceding `[` and trailing `]`.
- **NULLIF()** converts an empty array to *`null`*

[image]